# Bootstrap vertical align and sub navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've a problem to position a two-dimensional-menue. 
It's in the same row like an image and i want to place it on the bottom of the row. Now it's placed on the top of the row and looks like this:

[Header how it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIK6.png)

Here my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <img src="stockpulse.png" class="img-rounded">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a  href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Action</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

It should look like this:

[Header with a dropup menue showing the subcategories on a subsite:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMaxY.png)

Is it right to use a dropdown menue in a navbar if i want to show the subcategories permanently? Or is a nav in a navbar more useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8xa5h/

Basically, all I did was adding a `margin-top` to the navbar according to the height of the image.

```
.navbar .nav {
    margin-top: 120px;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking about a bootstrap only solution but this will do the job. :)