# Center content vertically in Twitter Bootstrap Grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I do not find a way to center content vertically in Twitter Bootstrap Grid system. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

For example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4" style="height:50px;min-height: 50px;">My centered object vertically</div>
</div>
```

The object in span4 div will always be at the top of div. I have tried to put `vertical-align: middle;` on parent and child Div's but that do not help.

Comment: Vertical alignment is not handled by Bootstrap, so it's only a CSS matter. You might find some info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11303461/1478467) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12882601/1478467)

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height or padding for it...

Like this for line-height,

```
.line-height { line-height:30px; }

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4 line-height">My centered object vertically</div>
</div>
```

Like this for padding, for 50px height minus it with the padding means ***paddingtop+height+paddingbottom = 50px***,

```
.padding { height:30px; padding:10px 0; }

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4 padding">My centered object vertically</div>
</div>
```